# Move File doesn't work in Laravel 4

Tags: laravel, file-upload

I am just using a form to upload a file and a simple route to move the file in my `/public/images` folder. But the moved file cant be found in the `images` directory. I am following Leanpub Laravel CodeBright book.

**my blade template**

```
 <form action="{{ url('handle-form') }}"
  method="POST"
  enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <input type="file" name="book" />
     <input type="submit">
  </form>
```

**route.php**

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    return View::make('form');
});

Route::post('handle-form', function()
{
    Input::file('book')->move('/public/images');
    return 'File was moved.';
});
```

After pressing submit button 'File was moved.' shown but there is no file in the desired directory.

Comment: Your webserver likely doesn't have permission to access `public/images`.

Comment: How can i allow my webserver to allow permission to access public/images?

Comment: Sorry i could not get your answer. I am new in laravel so if u elaborately give the answer i will be benefited.

Comment: But in the book it says if the user has no write access to the directory then a exception will be thrown but i am not getting any exceptions @ceejayoz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. I just remove leading '/' from the '/public/images' and its working fine.Now i am using 'public/images'.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted.

Comment: But @MartinBean i cant understand the difference.In the book the defined method does not work for me. But why?

Comment: Because if you put a slash in front of a path, it makes it _absolute_.